# Optimizing a while loop that contains PDO query's

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, notifications, query-optimization

**Information**

Currently building an notification page which lists all of the logged in users notifications which contain information about the notification on each one.

For example, without information

```
You have an unread message
```

With information

```
<Sarah> Sent you an message
```

**Problem**

Because the notifications require data such as Username (for message notifications) or a article title (say your following an author and they release a new blog post, one notification would need to pull username form users table and then also the title of the blog from the blog table) this causes my page to lag even on localhost which I'm guessing would get significantly worse once uploaded and tested in the wild.

**Current Code**

```
function showNotifications($userid){
    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE user_id = :userid ORDER BY timestamp DESC');
    $STH->execute(array(':userid' => $userid));
    while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $this->sortNotif($row);
}
```

Quick explanation about the function below, because I have different types of notifications I created a bunch of ID's for specific types, for example type 1 = new message, type 2 = new blog post

```
function sortNotif($notif){

    switch ($notif['type']) {

        case "1":
            $msg = $this->getMessageData($notif['feature_id']);
            $user = $this->userData($msg['sender']);
            echo '<li><i>'.timeAgo($notif['timestamp']).'</i><a href="user.php?username='.$user['username'].'">'.$user['first_name'].'</a> sent you a <a href="inbox.php?message='.$msg['id'].'">message</a></li>';
            break;

    }

}
```

As you can see for just showing that a user has a new message it creates 2 query's and once looped through 40 or so notifications, over 100 or so users becomes a strain on the server.

**Final Words**

If anyone needs more information please ask and I'll be sure to update this question asap, thanks!

**Edit**

Below are table structures as requested in the below comments.

notifications

```
id | user_id | feature_id | type | timestamp | read
```

users

```
id | username | password | first_name | last_name | email | verify_hash | avatar | type
```

messages

```
id | receiver | sender | replying_to | deleted | body | timestamp | read
```

Comment: could you take some common code out of switch/case statement in your sortNotif funtion? Did you analyze your queries using MySQL EXPLAIN or something ? any scope for optimization there ?

Comment: I used a small php snippet I found online and tested multiple pages multiple times. The notification.php page takes "Page generated in 0.6599 seconds." Whereas all the others "Page generated in 0.0467 seconds."

Also, the page is actually noticeably slower by eye. If you want I can try another method to test the speeds if there is anything you can suggest?

Comment: In that case could there be something else that might be slowing down your final page? javascript or images maybe ?

Comment: I looked in the chrome dev tools network tab and its only the .php file that is loading slow, the rest is near instant.

Comment: maybe you can try combining the 2 functions (showNotifications and sortNotif) into one? I think multiple switch statements which iterating through the while loop might be slowing down the whole code.

Comment: is `$this->getMessageData($notif['feature_id'])` generating a query as well?

Comment: So you think the switch statement is causing the lags rather than the multiple query's per sort?

Comment: That will slow you down significantly, since instead of two queries, you have `1 + number of notification` queries running. Before I can offer up further advice, can you post the relevant database structure?

Comment: @miah Sure thing, not too sure how you want it formatted but ill give it a go for users, notifications and messages. Give me a moment.

Comment: @miah I have updated the question with table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change of plan, since I misunderstood the set up.

You will want to pull all of the data from each of the 'type' tables in one go, rather than on a per notification basis.  This means that you will need to loop through your notifications twice, once to grab all the ids and appropriate types and then a second time to output the results.

```
function showNotifications($userid){
    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE user_id = :userid ORDER BY timestamp DESC');
    $STH->execute(array(':userid' => $userid));

    // Centralized Book keeping for the types.
    // When you add a new type to the entire system, add it here as well.
    $types = array();

    // Add the first notification type
    $types["1"] = array();
    // "query" is pulling all the data you need concerning a notification
    $types["1"]["query"] = "SELECT m.id, u.username, u.firstname FROM messages m, users u WHERE m.sender = u.id AND m.id IN ";
    // "ids" will hold the relevant ids that you need to look up.
    $types["1"]["ids"] = array();

    // A second type, just for show.
    // $types["2"] = array();
    // $types["2"]["query"] = "SELECT a.id, u.username, u.firstname FROM articles a, users u WHERE a.sender = u.id AND a.id IN ";
    // $types["2"]["ids"] = array();

    // Use fetchAll to gather all of the notifications into an array
    $notifications = $STH->fetchAll();

    // Walk through the notifications array, placing the notification id into the corret
    // "ids" array in the $types array.
    for($i=0; $i< count($notifications); $i++){
        $types[$notifications[$i]['type']]["ids"][] = $notifications[$i]['feature_id'];
    }

    // Walk through the types array, hit the database once for each type of notification that has ids.
    foreach($types as $type_id => $type){
        if(count($type["ids"]) >  0){
            $STH = $this->database->prepare($type["query"] . "( " . implode(",", $type["ids"]) . " )");
            $STH->execute();
            // Creates a hash table with the primary key as the array key
            $types[$type_id]['details'] = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $types[$type_id]['details'] = array_map('reset', $types[$type_id]['details']);
            // run array_map to make it easier to work with, otherwise it looks like this:
            // $results = array(
            //     1234 => array(0 => array('username' => 'abc', 'firstname' => '[...]')),
            //     1235 => array(0 => array('username' => 'def', 'firstname' => '[...]')),
            // );
        }
    }

    // Now walk through notifications again and write out based on notification type,
    // referencing $types[<notification type>]["details"][<message id>] for the details
    for($i=0; $i< count($notifications); $i++){

        // check to see if details for the specific notification exist.
        if(isset($types[$notifications[$i]['type']]["details"][$notifications[$i]['feature_id']])){
            $notification_details = $types[$notifications[$i]['type']]["details"][$notifications[$i]['feature_id']];

            switch ($notifications[$i]['type']) {

                case "1":
                    echo '<li><i>'.timeAgo($notifications[$i]['timestamp']).'</i><a href="user.php?username=' . $notification_details['username'] . '">' . $notification_details['first_name'].'</a> sent you a <a href="inbox.php?message='.$notifications[$i]['feature_id'].'">message</a></li>';
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** : Added logic to skip a notification if no details are pulled (ex. either the message or the user were deleted)

<strike>I think you want to run a single query that gathers all the info either via joins or a more complicated where statement.</strike>

Option 1: *this might need to be tweaked so as to not the cartesian product of the tables*

```
SELECT n.id, n.type, m.id, m.body, u.username, u.first_name 
FROM notifications n, messages m, users u
WHERE n.user_id = :userid AND m.id = n.feature_id AND u.id = m.sender
```

Option 2: *if the table aliases don't work, then you'll need to replace them with the full table name*

```
SELECT SELECT n.id, n.type, m.id, m.body, u.username, u.first_name 
FROM notifications n
    JOIN messages m
        ON n.feature_id = m.id
    JOIN users u
        ON m.sender = u.id
WHERE n.user_id = :userid
```

Comment: But I will have many different types of notifications in the future. for messages, for articles, for users etc. I cannot grab all the information at once surely?

Comment: What's the point in posting an answer that have to be "tweaked"?

Comment: @Harry will all of your `types` be in the messages table, with the same basic format of sender, receiver, body? if so, then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @miah No,I mentioned about having multiple types of notifications under the heading "Problem". For example an article notification might need to grab information from a different table. That is why I wanted to use the switch function as it is really easily expandable for new types of notifications.

Comment: @Harry I changed my answer to provide one possible implementation that hits the db once for all notifications and then one time for each of the notification types.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your updated post. Its going to take me a little while to get a grasp of it, but thank you! Also, will this still display notifications in the correct order(timestamp DESC)?

Comment: I think I am getting a understanding of this. It is really well written and being self taught I don't get to understand nor use well written code like this, its beautiful. Thank you. One last question though, I keep getting an error for notifications that cannot get the message information because that user / message has been deleted ( which is understandable ) What would be the best way to implement a quick feature that skips the notification if any of the information doesn't still exist? (possibly when $notification_details is being sent as thats the line that the error happens?)

Comment: @harry Great! Can post your updated code to your question? (_you should keep everything that is already there for context and just add the new code to the bottom_) That will make it a little bit easier to help you trouble shoot

Comment: @miah I havn't edited anything. Its just that if there was a message where the user has been deleted it would say Notice: Undefined offset: 6 on the line that $notification_details is set.

Comment: @miah thanks! works perfectly! There is an error on the new if statement, just missing a closing ")". Purely for the future if anyone uses this.

Comment: @harry just out of curiosity, what is the page generation time with this new code?

Comment: @miah Page generated in 0.0582 seconds. :)